# How to format Excel numbers so that >= 0.1 has 1 significant digit, but < 0.1 has two significant digits?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to figure out how to format numbers in Excel to display as follows: 
If the number is >= 0.1, there should be one digit after the decimal place, rounded up, but if it's < 0.1, there should be two digits after the decimal place.

So, for example:

```
entered | displayed
--------+----------
0.08      0.08
0.1       0.1
0.17      0.2
30.33     30.3
```

I tried entering various types of number formatting:

```
[<0.1]#.##,#.#
[<0.1]#.0#,#.#
```

However, these don't correctly display the data the way I want.  How can I display the data as desired?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the below custom number format:

```
[<0.1]0.00;[>=0.1]0.0
```

You were more or less there

You had entered the `<` criteria and format

You just needed to specify `>=` part